# Second occurrence of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the second occurrence of checkbox ?
Here is what I have tried:

```
<div id="form">
    <label for="first">First</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="first" value="1" >
    <br />
    <label for="second">Second</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="second" value="2" >
    <br />
</div>

$('#form').find('input[type=checkbox]').eq(1)
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/tjYDG/)

Comment: Works in my chrome with jquery 1.7. Can you give a more detailed error explanation? (Also I would just use `$('#form input[type="checkbox"]:eq(1)')` or `$('#form :checkbox:eq(1)')`)

Comment: If you name the checkboxes correctly, you could be more specific with `$("#form :checkbox[name='second']")`.

Comment: Maybe you're running your code to soon, have a look at [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect:

```
$('#form').find('input[type=checkbox]').eq(1)
```

should be:

```
$('#form').find('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(1)
```

You can do this also like that (proof in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwJzv/1/)):

```
jQuery('#form :checkbox[name="second"]:eq(1)');
```

(notice using `:checkbox` selector, enclosing `eq(1)` within the selector and merging selectors - form selector, `.find()` call and `.eq()` call)

Comment: @John: Maybe it works for you, but you should really take a look at [jQuery selectors documentation on " _attribute equals_ "](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), especially this part about attribute value: **Quotes are mandatory**

Comment: @Tadeck This is how it must be done, I agree, but from 1.5 an on it works eitherway.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = function(){
  var inputs = document.getElementById('form').getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){
    var checkbox = inputs[i];
    if(checkbox.type == 'checkbox' && checkbox.name == 'second'){
      return checkbox;
    }
  }
};
```

In pure JS you could do something like this :)

Comment: It looks like overkill in comparison to `jQuery('#form :checkbox[name="second"]:eq(1)')` ;)

Comment: it looks like a overkill to me, everytime I see sites including the full jquery lib and using about 1% of what jquery is capable of ;)

Comment: I would rather see such cases instead of poorly written raw JavaScript based on global variables, written in a manner not suitable for JavaScript. Thanks to jQuery there is less place for showing incompetence, breaking sites, making users angry etc. Btw. I like your code - it is better than most JS code on SO, but I still think it is an overkill (especially if OP already uses jQuery for other tasks, I guess). Anyway I give +1 for nice & correct code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the name of the second checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Give each checkbox an id and do something like

```
var $checkBox = $("#checkboxid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me, you could also do:

```
$('#form input:checkbox:last')
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ephWb/

Answer (score 0):

$('#form').find('input[type=checkbox]').eq(1) selects the item. You have to do something afterwards. In example:

```
$('#form').find('input[type=checkbox]').eq(1).val('5'); //Changes the value to 5
$('#form').find('input[type=checkbox]').eq(1).hide(); //hides it
```